# How to retrieve only one record with eager loading in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have **Eloquent** model **User** with relation **languages**

```
class User extends Model {

  // ... some code 

  public function languages()
  {
     return $this->belongsToMany(Language::class);
  }
}
```

My migration pivot table for ManyToMany relation

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('language_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('language_id');
        $table->primary(['user_id', 'language_id']);
    });
}
```

In the controller I try to get my **User**

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
     public function show(User $user)
     {
        return response()->success($user->with('languages')->get());
     }
}
```

But unfortunately instead of one user, I gets as result array of **Users**
How can I query only one **user** record with his **languages**?

Comment: you can use `pluck()` for that `return response()->success($user->with('languages')->pluck());`

Comment: Does the array contain multiple users?

Comment: @TimSch yep. Yes it is the problem

Comment: As I remember the get() method is only needed for collections. You access a single user and shouldn't need the get() here. What do you get without it?

Comment: You can use `load` to lazy eager load the language `relations`:  `$user->load('languages');`

Comment: Remul is right: https://www.amitmerchant.com/Laravel-Eager-Loading-Load-Vs-With/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Laravels *Lazy Eager Loading*:

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

> Sometimes you may need to eager load a relationship after the parent
>   model has already been retrieved.

In your case:

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
     public function show(User $user)
     {
        return response()->success($user->load('languages'));
     }
}
```